# Arrow appears on the left when using \vec

Tags: math-mode

When I work in atom today, when using the command \vec, the arrow appears on the upper left corner of the text. I have never had this problem before, and my old files compiled just fine. This is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, enumerate, graphicx, siunitx, amsthm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

  $\vec{a}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The following is the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.9.11)  7 NOV 2021 16:05
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**"Question 1.tex"
(./Question 1.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-08-27>
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count182
\c@section=\count183
\c@subsection=\count184
\c@subsubsection=\count185
\c@paragraph=\count186
\c@subparagraph=\count187
\c@figure=\count188
\c@table=\count189
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/04/20 v2.17j AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen139
))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen140
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count190
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count191
\leftroot@=\count192
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count193
\DOTSCASE@=\count194
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box50
\strutbox@=\box51
\big@size=\dimen141
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count195
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count196
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count197
\dspbrk@lvl=\count198
\tag@help=\toks17
\row@=\count199
\column@=\count266
\maxfields@=\count267
\andhelp@=\toks18
\eqnshift@=\dimen142
\alignsep@=\dimen143
\tagshift@=\dimen144
\tagwidth@=\dimen145
\totwidth@=\dimen146
\lineht@=\dimen147
\@envbody=\toks19
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks20
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty
Package: enumerate 2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
\@enLab=\toks21
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2020/12/05 v1.2c Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks22
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen148
\Gin@req@width=\dimen149
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty
Package: siunitx 2021-09-06 v3.0.29 A comprehensive (SI) units package
\l__siunitx_angle_tmp_dim=\dimen150
\l__siunitx_angle_marker_box=\box52
\l__siunitx_angle_unit_box=\box53
\l__siunitx_compound_count_int=\count268

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations.sty
Package: translations 2021/01/17 v1.10a internationalization of LaTeX2e package
s (CN)

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count269
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
))
\l__siunitx_number_exponent_fixed_int=\count270
\l__siunitx_number_min_decimal_int=\count271
\l__siunitx_number_min_integer_int=\count272
\l__siunitx_number_round_precision_int=\count273
\l__siunitx_number_group_minimum_int=\count274

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
Package: color 2020/02/24 v1.2b Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 149.
)
\l__siunitx_table_tmp_box=\box54
\l__siunitx_table_tmp_dim=\dimen151
\l__siunitx_table_column_width_dim=\dimen152
\l__siunitx_table_integer_box=\box55
\l__siunitx_table_decimal_box=\box56
\l__siunitx_table_before_box=\box57
\l__siunitx_table_after_box=\box58
\l__siunitx_table_before_dim=\dimen153
\l__siunitx_table_carry_dim=\dimen154
\l__siunitx_unit_tmp_int=\count275
\l__siunitx_unit_position_int=\count276
\l__siunitx_unit_total_int=\count277

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2021-08-27 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-08-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count278
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box59
))
Package: l3keys2e 2021-08-27 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2021/04/20 v2.5e Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen155
\ar@mcellbox=\box60
\extrarowheight=\dimen156
\NC@list=\toks23
\extratabsurround=\skip52
\backup@length=\skip53
\ar@cellbox=\box61
))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
\thm@style=\toks24
\thm@bodyfont=\toks25
\thm@headfont=\toks26
\thm@notefont=\toks27
\thm@headpunct=\toks28
\thm@preskip=\skip54
\thm@postskip=\skip55
\thm@headsep=\skip56
\dth@everypar=\toks29
)
Package translations Info: No language package found. I am going to use `englis
h' as default language. on input line 6.
 (./Question 1.aux)
\openout1 = `"Question 1.aux"'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count279
\scratchdimen=\dimen157
\scratchbox=\box62
\nofMPsegments=\count280
\nofMParguments=\count281
\everyMPshowfont=\toks30
\MPscratchCnt=\count282
\MPscratchDim=\dimen158
\MPnumerator=\count283
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count284
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks31
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations-basic-dictionar
y-english.trsl
File: translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl (english translation file `tra
nslations-basic-dictionary')
)
Package translations Info: loading dictionary `translations-basic-dictionary' f
or `english'. on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 10.

 (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 10.


(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
) [1

{c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./Question 1.a
ux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 6123 strings out of 478599
 141779 string characters out of 5858101
 413092 words of memory out of 5000000
 23960 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 409286 words of font info for 49 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 73i,5n,81p,402b,513s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
<c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><c:/
texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb><c:/texlive/2
021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi8.pfb><c:/texlive/2021/texmf-
dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts
/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb>
Output written on "Question 1.pdf" (1 page, 53766 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 33 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 19 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please post a minimal complete document that reproduces your error? Without such an example we can only guess what might cause this; we can help you much better and faster, if you provide some code showing your issue.

Comment: Hi, I have added an example

Comment: It compiles fine for me. What compiler and what version are you using?

Comment: So I'm using atom with package latextools and the builder is texlive 2021

Comment: Your editor choice is unlikely to affect this, what was meant is do you compile this with LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, or XeLaTeX?

Comment: @Skillmon, it is pdfLatex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, It is now included in the question! :)

Comment: Your test document [makes this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkVPG.png) with texlive 2021, please show the complete log that you get from your docuemnt.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi, I have included the log file

Comment: thanks that's very weird, apart from me having a version of siunitx a day or so newer it all looks the same and reports the same fonts, and I would guess you could remove siunitx and still show the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried removing every package it still looks the same...

Comment: Update: now solved, appears to be the problem with pdf-viewer in atom...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because viewer issue according to the comments.